# How to signal if a value has been read from a channel in Go

Tags: go, concurrency

I am reading values that are put into a channel `ch` via an infinite `for`. I would like some way to signal if a value has been read and operated upon (via the `sq` result) and add it to some sort of `counter` variable upon success. That way I have a way to check if my channel has been exhausted so that I can properly exit my infinite `for` loop.

Currently it is incrementing regardless if a value was read, thus causing it to exit early when the `counter == num`. I only want it to count when the value has been squared.

EDIT: Another approach I have tested is to receive the `ok` `val` out of the channel upon reading and setting `val` and then check if !ok { break }. However I receive a deadlock panic since the `for` did has not properly `break`. Example here: https://go.dev/play/p/RYNtTix2nm2

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    num := 5

    // Buffered channel with 5 values.
    ch := make(chan int, num)
    defer close(ch)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        go func(val int) {
            fmt.Printf("Added value: %d to the channel\n", val)
            ch <- val
        }(i)
    }

    // Read from our channel infinitely and increment each time a value has been read and operated upon
    counter := 0
    for {
        // Check our counter and if its == num then break the infinite loop
        if counter == num {
            break
        }
        val := <-ch
        counter++
        go func(i int) {
            // I'd like to verify a value was read from ch & it was processed before I increment the counter
            sq := i * i
            fmt.Println(sq)
        }(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sends and receives on unbuffered channels are synchronous. The values are received the moment they are sent, and there is no "exhausting" the channel, it cannot contain any values.

Comment: @JimB so if I buffer it with say the value of num. How can I then signal that all values have been read from the channel? I updated my answer with a buffered version. I ultimately just want to be able to signal when values have been processed from my channel so I can signal that the initial goroutines have done their work.

Comment: You signal when no more values will be sent to a channel by closing the channel. I suggest going through the Tour of Go, specifically the section on [Concurrency](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/1)

Comment: " it is incrementing regardless if a value was read" it is incrementing after `val := <-ch` which will block until a value is read.  "I only want it to count when the value has been squared" `sync.WaitGroup` is a simple mechanism to wait for the squaring goroutines to complete.  "That way I have a way to check if my channel has been exhausted" Whenever possible have the producer `close` the channel once all values have been sent.

Comment: @erik258 I am not seeing the final iteration of ```fmt.Prinln(sq)``` here: ```https://go.dev/play/p/ajk9ZfLH4Ts```. This to me seems like the function is exiting early for some reason.

Comment: `main` does not wait for other goroutines automatically.  You have to do that yourself.  a Wait Group is one easy way of doing it.  JimB's link on Concurrency will help you out

Comment: @erik258 I read JimB's tutorial and I edited my code to add in some Waitgroup functionality to control my goroutines and remove the infinite for loop, but it still continues to run as it hits a deadlock. see: https://go.dev/play/p/TuXJJiq1Ucr

Comment: Suggest you make that into a new question

Answer (score 2):

let me try to help you in figuring out the issue.

#### Reading issue

The latest version of the code you put in the question is working except when you're about to read values from the `ch` channel. I mean with the following code snippet:

```golang
go func(i int) {
  // I'd like to verify a value was read from ch & it was processed before I increment the counter
  sq := i * I
  fmt.Println(sq)
}(val)
```

In fact, it's not needed to spawn a new goroutine for each read. You can consume the messages as soon as they arrived in the `ch` channel. This is possible due to writing done inside goroutines. Thanks to them, the code can go ahead and reach the reading phase without being blocked.

#### Buffered vs unbuffered

In this scenario, you used a buffered channel with 5 slots for data. However, if you're relying on the buffered channel you should signal when you finish sending data to it. This is done with a `close(ch)` invocation after all of the Go routines finish their job. If you use an unbuffered channel it's fine to invoke `defer close(ch)` next to the channel initialization. In fact, this is done for cleanup and resource optimization tasks. Back to your example, you can change the implementation to use unbuffered channels.

#### Final Code

Just to recap, the two small changes that you've to do are:

1. Use an unbuffered channel instead of a buffered one.
2. Do Not use a Go routine when reading the messages from the channel.

Please be sure to understand exactly what's going on. Another tip can be to issue the statement: `fmt.Println("NumGoroutine:", runtime.NumGoroutine())` to print the exact number of Go routines running in that specific moment.

The final code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    num := 5

    // Buffered channel with 5 values.
    ch := make(chan int)
    defer close(ch)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        go func(val int) {
            fmt.Printf("Added value: %d to the channel\n", val)
            ch <- val
        }(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("NumGoroutine:", runtime.NumGoroutine())

    // Read from our channel infinitely and increment each time a value has been read and operated upon
    counter := 0
    for {
        // Check our counter and if its == num then break the infinite loop
        if counter == num {
            break
        }
        val := <-ch
        counter++
        func(i int) {
            // I'd like to verify a value was read from ch & it was processed before I increment the counter
            sq := i * i
            fmt.Println(sq)
        }(val)
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you, thanks!